# Does Snape have a bad hairstyle according to the wizarding world?

Tags: harry-potter

Having read a lot of fanfiction, I just realized that the Potion Master's hair has never been described in a flattering manner. The phrase ***greasy-haired*** has been used to describe Severus Snape in most fanfiction where Snape is portrayed as an antagonist.

*Does this common theme have an origin in canon?*

The following are a few examples of such fanfic instances for your perusal.

---

> "I shall take your wisdom into consideration," Severus said neutrally.
>
> "Also, try a different brand of ***hair shampoo***."
>
> A wry grin crossed Severus's face, and Harry thought it might have
>   been, for the first time, that man's true smile. "Drop dead, Potter."

-<sub>*Harry Potter and the Methods of Rationality*</sub>

---

Comment: Have you actually read the canon books?

Comment: @Randal Of course, why do you ask?

Comment: I just found it strange that you noticed frequent descriptions of his hair in *fanfiction* and not the equally frequent descriptions in the canon.

Comment: @Rand It's been a long time since I read the canon books... On the other hand, I read fanfic more frequently.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

JKR is in the habit of giving readers a pen portrait of each character *once per book*, including a physical description. These tend to be fairly repetitive.

> Professor Quirrell, in his absurd turban, was talking to **a teacher
> with greasy black hair,** a hooked nose and sallow skin.
>
> <sub><sup>HP and the Philosopher's Stone</sup></sub>

and

> Harry spun around. There, his black robes rippling in a cold breeze, stood Severus Snape. He was a thin man with sallow skin, a hooked nose **and greasy, shoulder-length black hair,** and at this moment, he was smiling in a way that told Harry he and Ron were in very deep trouble.
>
> <sub><sup>HP and the Chamber of Secrets</sup></sub>

and

> Snape approached their table, stared down his hooked nose at the roots, then gave Ron an unpleasant smile from beneath **his long, greasy black hair.**
>
> <sub><sup>HP and the Prisoner of Azkaban</sup></sub>

etc etc

Comment: This is true, but to me does not answer the question. There is no comparison of his hairstyle to that of other witches and wizards

Comment: @Ginge - The word greasy-haired cannot possibly indicate a good hairstyle

Comment: That refers to the look of the hair, not the style. One could use a lot of hair gel, which would make their hair look greasy, while still having an amazing hairstyle.